# Comparing two accounts, by the answers of them, with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to save the data on Firebase, that a user describes on an Intent. The saved data should be used to find one or more matching users with similar informations. 
Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are building an app where you can clusters users with similar interests about particular thing, i would suggest you to use [firebase firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) for storing data, and you can retrieve data that are similar using the firebase [simple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=1#simple_queries) and [compound](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=1#compound_queries) query depending on your requirement.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your advice. I created a Database, but how can I now manage the data from users ?